# remove viewpager programmatically

Tags: android, android-viewpager

my app implements navigationdrawer and viewpager (with PagerSlidingTabStrip). there're 3 menus in my navigationdrawer. I want to display different 'pages' (i don't know what it's called), according to what I chose in the navigationdrawer. I totally don't want to implement viewpager on the first 'page', but for the rest I'd like to have viewpager. How should I do this?

below is a fragment of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

        // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
        tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabstrip);
        pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    }

private class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final String[] TITLES = { "Categories", "Home", "Top Paid", "Top Free", "Top Grossing", "Top New Paid"};

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return TITLES[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TITLES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return MyFragment.newInstance("yess" + position);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        //Toast.makeText(this, "selected " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (position == 0){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PageHome.newInstance())
                    .commit();
        }else{
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

if u can see above, if position == 0 which means the 1st page, PageHome would be called, and it doesn't want to have anything to do with viewpager. else, the other 'pages' would have viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Make a different Fragment for each page in your navigation list. In your Activity's layout XML, leave an empty FrameLayout as the content area. On first launch, in onCreate you can add the first Fragment to this container.

```
 <DrawerLayout ...>
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/content_area" ... />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer" ... />
</DrawerLayout>

protected void onCreate(Bundle saved) {
    super.onCreate(saved);

    /* other code ... */

    if (saved == null) {
        // no saved instance state, add the first fragment
        Fragment1 fragment = ... // (create new)
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_area, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

Then whenever the user selects a different page in your navigation drawer, you can replace the current fragment with the one they selected. Use a ViewPager only within the Fragments that need it.

Comment: sorry for this late reply, as I was attached to another project. I'm still puzzled by this; and this is what I did:

Comment: I did what you suggested on the 'if (saved == null)' part, but where should I put all the 'tabs = PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabstrip); pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager); adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()); pager.setAdapter(adapter); tabs.setViewPager(pager);' code?

Comment: Inside the fragment that has the ViewPager and PagerSlidingTabStrip

Comment: sorry @Karakuri can you be more clear? I have re-asked this question in a more proper way here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903309/viewpager-with-navigationdrawer .. can you help me there? tq

Comment: Make a fragment for each item in your NavigationDrawer. Each fragment should entirely encapsulate the logic for that section; if that section needs a ViewPager, use it in the Fragment. The activity is only responsible for swapping fragments when the user selects something from the NavigationDrawer.